# ThreeJS WebGLRenderTarget has blank texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Using A-Frame and Three.JS, I want to render to a WebGLRenderTarget and create a material based on its texture, like so:

```
var targetPlane = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'})
);
targetPlane.position.set(-2, 1, -2);
scene.add(targetPlane);

var redPlane = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'})
);
redPlane.position.set(2, 1, -2);
scene.add(redPlane);

var myCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 1000);
myCamera.position.set(2, 1, 0);
scene.add(myCamera);

var myRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
myRenderer.setSize(200, 200);
myRenderer.render(scene, myCamera);

var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(200, 200, {minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                                                           magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter});
myRenderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget);
myRenderer.render(scene, myCamera);

targetPlane.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: renderTarget.texture});
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

The outcome is just a blank white material. The camera settings are correct. The following code works:

```
 myRenderer.setRenderTarget(null);
 myRenderer.render(scene, myCamera);
 img.src = myRenderer.domElement.toDataURL();
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mpx2e3n/2/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a render target produced by a `WebGLRenderer` with a different instance of `WebGLRenderer` because WebGL resources like buffers, textures or shader programs can't be shared across WebGL contexts.

Hence, you have to use `renderer` to produce the render target and to render the final scene.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4snr9tq/

`three.js R112`.